# Interpretación del concepto de TTL en Azure Data Factory Integration Runtime

Tags: azure

Buen día.

He estado tratando de buscar información (y preguntando en otros foros) acerca del concepto de TTL en el integration Runtime (IR) de Azure Data Factory (ADF). Qué determina exactamente ese valor?

Supongamos que tengo dos pipelines y cada uno de ellos con dos dataflows que apuntan al mismo IR: Generic, 8 cores y 10 TTL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando el pipeline número uno se ejecuta, su primer dataflow es el encargado de preparar el ambiente. Pero cuando este flujo concluye, que pasá con los otros 3 dataflows, sólo tienen 10 minutos para poder completarse?

Si ejecuto (trigger) el segundo pipeline cuando el dataflow número uno a finalizado, el 3 y el 4 ya podrían hacer uso de este ambiente, o el tres también tendría que adquirir recursos para su ejecución?